# Error Gibberish download file from sharepoint using rest api

Tags: rest

I need to download a file from a sharepoint list using the rest api, the endpoint I use is the following:

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/testsit**strong text**e/SiteAssets/Lists/411sec72-5b2d-2014-n8fx5-qt1b9b5a4blp')/files('profile.png')/$value
```

returns Gibberish strange encoding[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely just looking at a png file as raw text. Try saving what you got as a png and open with photos app.
[image]

I saved your screenshot as a png and opened it on my computer in vim.

Comment: thanks for the comment, is there a way to download the file (png, jpeg, pdf, docx) without adding the file extension manually?

Comment: You should probably find the user name of the profile.png and name them something like $user+'.png'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the SharePoint rest api doesn't provide the image/png content type header in the response, so Postman doesn't realize that the data there is a png file.

You should be able to save the data to a local file though, giving it the correct name/extension.

[image]

Whatever code you end up using to call the rest api and save the file should be able to write the image to a file with the appropriate name.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this works if I save the document with the correct extension

Answer (score 0):

You can download the documents using below endpoint. One drawback is that this works only for PDF documents and Images.

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/namesite/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl={ServerRelativeUrl}
```

You can get the **ServerRelativeUrl** by making a call to the document library endpoint or the attachment of your list.